# how can change backkground-color and border-radius of v-data-table header in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to style my `v-data-table` header like the one you see in the image below.

[link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjuor.png)

So far, I've tried adding the style directly with CSS:

```
<v-data-table
 :headers="headers"
 :items="desserts"
 hide-default-footer
 class="custom_table_class"   
>

</v-data-table>
```

```css
.custom_table_class > div > table > thead {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The code above only changes the **background color** but, not the **border radius**.

Is there a way to make something like the image you see with vuetify's `v-data-table`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use !important here, to override the current styling. try this: border-radius: 10px !important;

Comment: I tried !important too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the CSS to the `<th>` elements:

```css
.custom_table_class thead th {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
}
.custom_table_class thead th:first-child {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.custom_table_class thead th:lsat-child {
  border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

Or, in SCSS:

```
.custom_table_class thead th {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  &:first-child { border-radius: 6px 0 0 0 }
  &:last-child { border-radius: 0 6px 0 0 }
}
```

See it working here: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/YzWdxGX